# axios.post is returning error when used with redux-saga

Tags: react-native, axios, redux-saga

I recently converted my redux-thunk middleware code to use redux-saga and it was working all these days fine and all of a sudden it is throwing an error. Not sure why!!

My Spring Boot REST Client is returning the proper response and no errors in the log. And if i make the same request using swagger i am getting the response back as expected so there is nothing wrong on the server side.

I have the following code

```
const LOGIN_URL = 'http://localhost:8888/api/a/login';

export function* loginUserAsync(action) {
    console.log('.loginUserAsync() : action:', action);
    yield put({ type: LoginConstants.LOGIN_USER_IN_PROGRESS });

    const postParams = {
          username: action.props.username,
          password: action.props.password
    };

    const headerParams = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          //'Content-Type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    };
    console.log('headerParams', headerParams);
    console.log('postParams', postParams);
    try {
        console.log('Before making async post call using axios');
        const response = yield call(axios.post, LOGIN_URL, postParams, headerParams);
        let token;
        console.log('response', response);
        if (response.headers) {
            token = response.headers['x-auth-token'];
            AsyncStorage.setItem('jwt', token);
        }
        // Login Succeeded fire Login Success Action
        yield put({
                type: LoginConstants.LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
                token,
                account: response.data
        });

        const navigatorUID = Store.getState().navigation.currentNavigatorUID;
        Store.dispatch(NavigationActions.push(navigatorUID, Router.getRoute('home')));
    } catch (error) {
        // Login Failed fire Login Failure Action
        console.log('loginUserAync() : error:[' + JSON.stringify(error) + ']');
        yield put({
                type: LoginConstants.LOGIN_USER_FAILURE,
                error: error.data
        });
    }
}

export function* loginUser() {
    console.log('.loginUser() :');
    yield takeEvery(LoginConstants.LOGIN_USER, loginUserAsync);
}
```

In the console i am seeing the following:

[image: Screenshot from remote debugging in Chrome]

I have no idea why it stopped working all of a sudden.

Thanks
Sateesh

Answer (score 0):

For some reason localhost and 127.0.0.1 are not being recognized and i have to use the actual IP Address.

I had that Issue when i tried to run it in my mac book. It always worked with localhost in Ubuntu.